# How can I access the files on my Ubuntu laptop from my phone if I am tethering?

Tags: usb, files, tethering

I am tethering my laptop from my phone.

Is there a way to access the file system on my laptop from the mobile phone while tethering? I would for example like to be able to access image files from my laptop on the phone. (Additional info: I do not have wifi access on the phone and I don't want to use 3G for transferring files locally).

Laptop: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S5

Comment: 15.10 is an old release so if it is not working you will likely have to at least upgrade to 16.04

Comment: How do you mean 'tethering the laptop from phone' ? Doesn't this means that you will have a outbound connection in laptop from the phone (3g)

Comment: Updated. Still need an answer

Comment: @Vesa 16.10 is also out of support. Currently supported releases are 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS, 17.04 and 17.10.

Comment: Updated. Still need an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use Python module to run a basic HTTP server and use a web browser on mobile phone to access the localhost PC via USB tethering.

### Overview of setup and usage

A mobile phone is connected to localhost PC via a USB cable.

- Setup on mobile phone (USB tethering is **enabled**)
- Setup on localhost PC (see **Part A.**)
- Access from mobile phone (see **Part B.**)

When user has finished access, go to localhost PC and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the HTTP server that is running in the terminal. Or simply closing the terminal may terminate the process as well.

### Part A: Setup on localhost PC

Ensure that Python is installed on the localhost PC (Run `python --version` in a terminal to check the version, which will affect step 3).

1. Open a terminal
2. First, check the IP address of localhost PC using `ip` or `ifconfig` command (whichever works). The following example output shows `192.168.XX.YYY` is the IP address that has been assigned to a localhost PC via USB tethering.

   ```
   $ ip addr show usb0 
   3: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
   link/ether **:**:**:**:**:** brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   inet 192.168.XX.YYY/** brd 192.168.XX.ZZZ scope global usb0
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet6 ****::****:****:****:****/** scope link 
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

   $ ifconfig usb0
   usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr **:**:**:**:**:**  
             inet addr:192.168.XX.YYY  Bcast:192.168.XX.ZZZ  Mask:255.255.255.0
             inet6 addr: ****::****:****:****:****/** Scope:Link
             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
             ...
   ```
3. Then, start an HTTP server using Python module with any available port number i.e. 31415 (Easy to remember as 'pi'). The following example shows `http.server` module is used for Python 3, otherwise use `SimpleHTTPServer` module for Python 2.

   ```
   $ python -m http.server <port_number>
   Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port ***** ...
   ```

Additionally, if localhost PC has enabled firewall, add a new rule to allow incoming connection from the port number and IP address (This would be another set of question and answer). Else temporarily disable firewall would just work for simplicity in exchange of low security.

### Part B: Access from mobile phone

Ensure that USB tethering *remain* enabled; No further configuration.

1. Open a web browser
2. Go to `http://192.168.XX.YYY:<port_number>` in which `192.168.XX.YYY` is the IP address used by localhost PC and `<port_number>` is any available port number on localhost PC.
3. The web browser will show **Directory listing** of current working directory, which by default is Home directory of current user.

User can now access any files and directories in the current working directory for browsing and download purpose.

### Limitation and compatibility

An HTTP server will allow read-only access, which is good enough for browsing and download purpose. User will *not* be able to modify files on the localhost PC. Should user need both read and write access, then use other method (Perhaps using SFTP or SSH, which I do not know).

The HTTP server method will work as long as USB tethering is enabled (IP address is known), regardless of Airplane Mode or Cellular Data is turned on or off. Likely work for mobile phones with any Android version (not sure for other mobile operating systems).

Tested using Python 2.7 and Python 3.4, with UFW enabled and disabled on Xubuntu 14.04 and USB tethering enabled on Android 7.1.1.

### References

- [SimpleHTTPServer — Simple HTTP request handler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) from Python 2 documentation.
- [http — HTTP modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html) from Python 3 documentation
- [How do you decide what port to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2200199) on Stack Overflow has discussed what port to use.
- [How to check opened/closed port on my computer?](https://askubuntu.com/q/538208) on Ask Ubuntu has mentioned commands to check opened or closed port on computer.

### Related posts on SE network

- [How do I share a folder with another Linux machine on the same home network?](https://askubuntu.com/q/15782) on Ask Ubuntu has one of the answers that mentioned SimpleHTTPServer but somewhat lack of explanation.
- [How can I access my desktop computer when its tethered to my Android phone?](https://superuser.com/q/456406) on Super User has discussed port forwarding using iptables.
- [How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4779963) on Stack Overflow has mixed answers that deal with emulator and real device.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution.

Making

```
sudo /sbin/ifconfig
```

then looking for

> enp0s20u2: {...}

that includes the following property:

> inet 192.168.xx.xxx

Was the good IP adress to look for in my case.

I have then connected to my computer's localhost from my mobile phone in tethering mode by entering in my mobile'phone URL's bar, the following adress:

```
// where PORT is effectively the computer localhost's port number 
// on which you want to connect.
inet 192.168.xx.xxx:{PORT}
```