# How to browse a linux network

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Safe Home Network through WiFi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51475/safe-home-network-through-wifi)

I have three PCs running Ubuntu.
Now I want to browse one PC from another one.
Why does Ubuntu only show Windows Network? I *don't* use Windows so I have no need for that nor for samba.
Where are my other Ubuntu PCs in my network? How to visualize them?